# ClassNotFoundException in Micronaut

Tags: gradle, executable-jar, noclassdeffounderror, micronaut

few days back  i starting learning micronaut ,Since last one week i am trying to resolve below exception but unable to resolve this .

I don't know why this application not able to find main class .Everything seems correct

I try many solution but none of them work for me .

I created basic demo application and created jar file then i used these command to run micronaut application using jar file but got below exception
CMD1

```
java -cp build/libs/demo2-0.1.jar  com.example.Application
```

CMD2

```
 java -jar build/libs/demo2-0.1.jar
```

Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "2.0.6"
    id 'java'
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micronaut/micronaut-runtime
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime:3.1.0")

    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
}





jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.Application'
        )
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micronaut/runtime/Micronaut
        at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

[image]

After running  given cmd in ans:

```
BLRETV-MMMMMM:demo2 User$ java -jar build/libs/demo2-0.1-all.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/demo2-0.1-all.jar
BLRETV-MMMMMM:demo2 User$ java -cp build/libs/demo2-0.1-all.jar  com.example.Application
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Application
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `-all` jar, i.e.

`java -cp build/libs/demo2-0.1-all.jar  com.example.Application`

or

`java -jar build/libs//demo2-0.1-all.jar`

Comment: Thanks for quick response .But these two command not working .I add result of two cmd above .Please help

Comment: One thing that might help - remove the version from `implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime:3.1.0")` - the plugin adds a Maven BOM which has the correct versions, so like the other Micronaut dependencies you don't need (and shouldn't use in case they're not compatible) to specify dependency versions

Comment: Also, `Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/demo2-0.1-all.jar` is probably a big hint as to the real problem

Comment: I think  demo2-0.1-all.jar does not exist in libs folder .it's demo2-0.1.jar(as you can see in picture above) that's why this error is come . if i run above cmd without "-all " i got NoClassfoundException

Comment: how did you run your build? it should work if you run `./gradlew assemble`

Comment: Thanks a lot  finally this cmd work for me "./gradlew assemble " it created a new jar file in lib folder with name "demo2-0.1-all.jar"

Comment: Previously demo2-0.1.jar file which i am using created by intellij (you can see in image, gradle option available on right task bar )

Answer (score 0):

I would advice first try and run the command line gradlew commands to make sure the app works with runtime.
try
`gradlew test` and also `gradlew run`

You may find our guides helpful as well.

https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/creating-your-first-micronaut-app-gradle-java.html